# The connection is closed JPA , hibernate , Java 1.6

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are using Hibernate and JPA for database operations, and we are also using JBoss datasource JNDI for connection pooling with Java 1.6

Whenever first time application tried to connect to DB "we face the connection is closed error" and sometimes in between we face the following  issue:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The
>   connection is closed. javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The connection is
>   closed.   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)    at
>   com.tm.iswift.ws.masterdata.CRDataDAOImpl.FetchData(CRDataDAOImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   com.tm.iswift.ws.masterdata.ClaimReferenceDataBOImpl.FetchData(ClaimReferenceDataBOImpl.java:53)
>     at
>   com.tm.iswift.ws.masterdata.ClaimReferenceDataService.masterData(ClaimReferenceDataService.java:90)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.

`persistence.xml` settings are:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="format_sql" value="true " />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
    </properties>
```

Following are the configuration for JPA: 
 we even tried retainmode and "always" and flushbeforequeries as "with-connection" but the same issue we faced as mentioned above,

```
 props.put("openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode", "transaction");
  props.put("openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries", "true");

  entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager(props);
  //entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
  entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
```

Following is the method of DAO where we face the issue manytimes :- 
      Here in backend it always contains some data to fetch for this method.

```html
 @Transactional // added
  public List<ClaimType> FetchData() throws ISwiftException {
    LOGGER.info("CRDataDAOImpl: FetchData: Enter");
    List<ClaimType> ctypes = null;
    Query lQuery = null;
    try {
     EntityManager em =getEntityManager();
     if (em.isOpen()){} // before assing this also same error we faced
     else {em =getEntityManager();} // before assing this also same error we faced
      lQuery = (Query) em.createNamedQuery("ClaimType.findAll");
   if (em.isOpen()){}   // before assing this also same error we faced
 else {em =getEntityManager();}   // before assing this also same error we faced
      ctypes = lQuery.getResultList();
      LOGGER.info("CRDataDAOImpl: FetchData: End");
      return ctypes;
    } catch (PersistenceException exception) {
      LOGGER.error("CRDataDAOImpl::FetchData()::REASON OF EXCEPTION=" + exception.getMessage(), exception);
      throw new ISwiftException(exception);
    } finally {
      closeEntityManager();
    }
  }
```

Could you please help on this or let me know the best way to interact with DB with Hibernate at the last if nothing works with existing configurations.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You connections are pooled by JBoss, and they go stale when idle for too long. To fix, specify a validation query where the JNDI datasource is defined.

Comment: Hi Andreas  ,thanks . could you please elaborate more "specify a validation query where the JNDI datasource is defined"

Comment: I got some online links for this  , will check ...Many thanks

Comment: Why are you posting configuration for OpenJPA when you say you are using Hibernate? You cannot be using BOTH!!!

Comment: Hi Andreas ,i can't find that option in jboss 6 ,

Comment: Hi Andreas ,i can't find that option in jboss 6 ,Valid Connection Checker:
Exactly where can I make changes ? 
 
Check Valid Sql:
 
Validate On Match

Background Validation:
 
Validation Millis:

Stale Connection Checker:
 
Exception Sorter:

Comment: I have configured the settings in Jboss like check valid sql , valid connection checker and validate on match settings in datasource,I will observe and update accordingly , Thanks all . Thanks Andreas.

Comment: Hi Andreas ,Great Help! . Most probably issue is resolved. Still I am observing the situation .Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had faced the same issues many times and what worked for me in most of the cases was getting the connection object manually and then using Result set object to execute queries against the database like mentioned below:

> Session session = (Session) entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
>
> Connection conn = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
>
> // here you can check if the connection object is null or not.
>
> ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(your string query);

Hope it helps

Comment: you mean don't use JPA and instead use JDBC ?! which kinda negates the point of using JPA, no? Why not fix the actual problem ...

Comment: I totally agree with you but there are exceptional scenarios which JPA does not support (or are quite tough with it) & for instance (not related with this question) but I tried to get a BLOB object from the Oracle database using entityManager and it was just impossible to obtain but however using ResultSet it was straightforward.

Comment: You have not determined whether the OP has some situation "outside the scope of JPA", you have simply said get the JDBC connection and hack it.

Comment: Exactly! I suggested what worked for me if you could read my post. Suggesting some thing that worked for me in such situation will not give any harm. It might work for him too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andreas!

ValidationQuery Could resolve an issue and jBOSS Datasrouce specific settings like "Check Valid Sql & Validate On Match" , related settings could resolve an issue.